# how to configure hibernate config file for sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, orm, hibernate.cfg.xml

Here is the config file for MySQL:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">zgy01</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">100</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="model.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What to specify for SQL Server 2005? I did it like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">lal</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">100</property>        
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="model.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My question more precisely is how to specify the database that I have to connect to?

In MySQL I used to do like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
```

Comment: Looks like the SQL Server `hibernate.connection.driver_class` has a copy/paste error? The value in `hibernate.connection.url` should be in the `driver_class` property and the URL should be a custom URL for the SQL Server database

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Properties that are *database specific* are:

- `hibernate.connection.driver_class`: JDBC driver class
- `hibernate.connection.url`: JDBC URL
- `hibernate.connection.username`: database user
- `hibernate.connection.password`: database password
- `hibernate.dialect`: The class name of a Hibernate `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` which allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular relational database.

To change the database, you must:

1. Provide an appropriate JDBC driver for the database on the class path,
2. Change the JDBC properties (**driver, url, user, password**)
3. Change the `Dialect` used by Hibernate to talk to the database

There are two drivers to connect to SQL Server; the open source [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and the Microsoft one. The driver class and the JDBC URL depend on which one you use.

### With the jTDS driver

The driver class name is `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`.

The URL format for sqlserver is:

```
 jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

So the Hibernate configuration would look like (note that you can skip the `hibernate.` prefix in the properties):

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>[:<port>][/<database>]</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password">lal</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

    ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### With Microsoft SQL Server JDBC 3.0:

The driver class name is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`.

The URL format is:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

So the Hibernate configuration would look like:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]];databaseName=<databaseName></property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password">lal</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

    ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Documentation
- [3.3. JDBC connections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc)
- [3.4. Optional configuration properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)
- [jTDS Documentation](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/doc.html)
- [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver <s>3.0</s> Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)
- [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver <s>2.0</s>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)
- [Support Matrix for Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix)

Comment: I had issues with 2012 & jTDS but got JDBC 4.0 to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404283/java-hibernate-with-sql-server-2012-not-working

Comment: In my case I had to ensure I was using the correct dialect for my Microsoft SQL Server. I use `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect` instead of the default `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` that seems to be for `Microsoft SQL Server 2000`. For 2005 in persistence.xml I would do `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect"/>`

Answer (score 8):

The connection URL should look like this for SQL Server:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://serverName[\instanceName][:port][;databaseName=your_db_name]
```

Examples:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost
jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\INGESQL:1433;databaseName=datatest
...
```

Answer (score 6):

We also need to mention default schema for SQSERVER: dbo

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
```

Tested with hibernate 4

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to enable tcp/ip connections in SQL SERVER Configuration tools

Answer (score 3):

Finally this is for `Hibernate 5` in `Tomcat`.

Compiled all the answers from the above and added my tips which works like a charm for `Hibernate 5 and SQL Server 2014`.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
   org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">  
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\ServerInstanceOrServerName:1433;databaseName=DATABASE_NAME 
</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">theSchemaNameUsuallydbo</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">
   YourUsername
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">
   YourPasswordForMSSQL
</property>
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep the jar files under web-inf lib incase you included jar and it is not able to identify .

It worked in my case where everything was ok but it was not able to load the driver class.

Comment: From Review: This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.