# migrating java app that accesses mysql to code that uses SQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, struts

I have with me a java app that uses mysql-- now I have converted the database to SQL Server- but I need to convert the code of the java app so that it now uses SQL Server.

This java app uses Struts and Hibernate

What all things do I have to keep in mind to make this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hibernate should make the transition seamless for you. 
Make sure to choose the correct driver as some drivers might act differently. 
I personally like [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/). It has vast documentation.

Look for native queries in your code because they might need some modifications.

Other than that, I don't think you should experience any problem. 
I had an application that supported oracle, SQL-Server and mysql and we didn't have specific code for each one.

EDIT : as maba suggests in the comments, you will need to modify the hibernate configuration a bit (driver, dialect, url ).

For more hibernate specific configuration, I found a [great stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3585544/1068746)

Comment: And also change the hibernate dialect.