# Hibernate configuration for MS SQL Server 2012 Standard

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2012

i am new to hibernate and need to configure it for MS SQL-server 2012 standard.
i found this deprecated article [how to configure hibernate config file for sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585544/how-to-configure-hibernate-config-file-for-sql-server) but i need a new one. where i can find the driver for the new database (if there is any)!
thanks for answers

Comment: What's the first result when you google for "MS SQL-server 2012 JDBC driver"?

Comment: yeah, but whats the dialect? is the sql server 2012 supported? the driver you can find here http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Comment: the dialect should be Microsoft SQL Server - org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect but a new one would be cool... and the server is not officialy tested

Comment: I don't know, but I would bet that the SQLServer2008Dialect is the one to use. I guess MS didn't revolutionize its SQL syntax, and kept backward compatibility. If there are problems, you can still use your own dialect that extends this one.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

to close the question: i am using oracle now. not because ms is not working...
the upper config could work...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404283/java-hibernate-with-sql-server-2012-not-working).

jTDS didn't work although it had previously worked with the same settings on SQL Server 2008 R2.

A couple config lines which MS JDBC 4.0 requires.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to give the user,password and database name in separate property tags,you can keep all of them inside url named proprety tag.
Inside Hibernate configuration file you can write like this:-

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://myhost;user=user1;password=pass1;database=Student1</property>
```

where `user1`,`pass1`,`myhost` and `Student1` are my credential, you can replace them by yours.