# Java Hibernate with SQL Server 2012 not working?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2012, jtds

I have a Java Hibernate project configuration which worked with SQL Server 2008 R2, now with a new OS 8.1 (from 7) and SQL Server 2012 (express), I'm unable to connect to SQL server.

Relevant configuration which is/should be [syntactically correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588652/878612) since it worked with 2008 R2:

**datasource.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dbname;instance=SQLEXPRESS
jdbc.username=auser
jdbc.password=xyz
```

I've tried two dialects `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` worked in 2008 R2.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

**springConfiguration.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

**SQL Server 2012** was installed with mixed mode authentication and SQL Server Management Studio has no problem connecting (with or without the instance name).

I've updated the `SQL Server Network Configuration` for `SQLEXPRESS`.

**Protocols for SQLEXPRESS:**

`TCP/IP Enabled`
As well as all of the `TCP/IP Properties - TCP Port`'s to 1433.

I've tried disabling Windows Firewall just to test if it's in the way but it results in the same error.

I ended up adding Firewall rules and following some of the steps in this excellent [configure SQL Express 2012 to accept remote connections article](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/).

The error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your problem is jTDS does not support the way DBCP2 validates a connection by default (I'm assuming you use DBCP2 from `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">`). See the solution below.

Usually the error stacktrace is as shown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:913)
```

The problem, though, is not related to the SQL Server version, but to the DBCP (Tomcat) version used (or the Tomcat server version the project is deployed to).

Once I was using jTDS 1.3.1 and the project worked fine (and connected to SQLServer 2012 as well) under Tomcat7. When I changed to Tomcat 8, that error appeared.

The reason, as [hinted in jTDS forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/discussion/104388/thread/bbfbcf24/), is:

- (*Tomcat7 uses DBCP 1 and Tomcat 8 uses DBCP 2*)
- Unlike **DBCP 1.x**, **DBCP 2** will call `java.sql.Connection.isValid(int)` to validate the connection
- jTDS doesn't implement `.isValid()`, so jTDS driver won't work with DBCP 2, unless...
- ...unless you set the `validationQuery` parameter, which will make DBCP not call `.isValid()` to test the validity of the connection.

### Workaround

So, the workaround is to **set the `validationQuery` parameter**, which will make DBCP2 not call `.isValid()` to test the validity of the connection. Here's how:

#### On Tomcat

Add `validationQuery="select 1"` to your Tomcat `<Resource>` tag for connection pool, which is usually in `META-INF/context.xml` of your app or `conf/server.xml`:

```
<Resource ... validationQuery="select 1" />
```

#### On Spring

When using DBCP2 through Spring, the solution is something around:

```
<bean id="..." ...> 
    ...
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
</bean>
```

#### On Simple java Code

```
dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
```

Comment: Excellent description of the problem. I went the Spring way and it works perfect. The accepted answer should considered as a workaround but this hits the core.

Comment: To which bean exactly should this property be added: the session factory or the data source?

Comment: @fasfsfgs To the **data source**.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) has some issues with SQL Server 2012 (update 2?) or something has changed in `2012/8.1` which previously worked in `2008 R2/7`.

Using nearly the same configuration as above with a [couple minor changes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), I downloaded and changed the datasource.properties to use [Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx).

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;
#jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\dbname:1433;
```

I just put the `sqljdbc4.jar` in `tomcat\lib\` to verify that the MS JDBC driver 4.0 works with SQL Server 2012 with all updates and it works perfectly. The dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` worked in 2012 too.