# Hibernate Migration SQL server 2005 to 2012 Drivers

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, hibernate

in my job we're migrating our MS SQL Server 2005 to 2012. Here we use Hibernate and the question that we're trying to figure out is, Why the applications work perfectly with the same configuration in the .cfg.xml and need no changes.

We had verified all the new version databases were were pointed correctly. So that mistake is not valid.

What I know is Hibernate hide the configuration of the connetion by the .cfg.xml but we're not sure why we don't need to upgrade or even change the xml file.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe change dialect to SQL Server 2012 : org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
you car see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585544/how-to-configure-hibernate-config-file-for-sql-server).

Comment: I resolve this, It result that the driver that we were using support since 2005 to 2012 version of SQL server.